# c# codedom create property which returns a dictionary element

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties, codedom

To create a property with backing field in codedom we can use a construction like this:

```
CodeMemberProperty property = new CodeMemberProperty;
           property.GetStatements.Add(
               new CodeMethodReturnStatement(
                   new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
                       new CodeThisReferenceExpression(),
                                                      fieldName)));
```

But what construction inside "CodeMethodReturnStatement" must be for a result like:

```
public string SomeProp { get { return _someDict[_someKey]; } }
```

Where:

```
_someDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
_someKey = "someKey";
```

_someDict and _someKey is members of same generated class.

Comment: I think you need the CodeIndexerExpression class.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include the answer. Instead, you should post it as an answer and then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to commentary I'll solved the problem like this:

```
CodeIndexerExpression indexerExpression =
            new CodeIndexerExpression(
                new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
                    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Class1)), 
                    "dict"),
                new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
                    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Class1)), 
                    "key"));
```

Note that my key field and dictionary field are static, but for local variables idea is the same.
Just use CodeThisReferenceExpression instead CodeTypeReferenceExpression.

```
    public static string Prop
    {
        get
        {
            return Class1.dict[Class1.key];
        }
    }
```